# Photos show up as blank after putting them on SD card

Tags: sd-card

Inserted a 32 GB Micro SD card. Phone recognizes it and I can copy photos on to it and they all appear to be there.

But when I restart the phone many of the photos show up blank. Any way to fix this?  I tried another card with similar results.

My phone runs Android 4.4.

Comment: Sorry, but cell and smart phone questions are off-topic. I've tag this to be moved to the [android.se] site. Please don't double post.

Comment: Do you have a "Scan Media" button in settings, or in the gallery or wherever they put it, it will scan the new stuff into the database.  When all else fails there is a trick of renaming the folder the items are in, and scanning again, which can "fix" the database from not knowing. I actually keep a scan media widget button out on the home screen to do that, when the database needs updating.

Answer (score 1):

Try erasing the photo gallery application data and reboot before starting the app again, so that it has to load again thumbnails and image locations once more when it starts. Perhaps it is not updating propper data.